# How to describe more future promises in a sentence

Tags: conjunction-reduction

If I want to say a sentence like this:

> I will go there and I will lock the door and I will tell them the
>   information.

I suppose that this is not a correct way. Should I use only the first *will* and the form the sentence like this?

> I will go there, lock the door and tell them the information.

Is the first example just grammatically incorrect or does it just sound weird?

Comment: I wouldn't say it was _incorrect_, it just looks clumsy to repeat 'I will' so many times. You might possibly say it that way if someone doubted your word and you were angrily stressing that you intended to do all three things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first version is grammatically correct, but, as you say, it sounds a bit odd. You might use this construct in some dramatic, sonorous passage or speech. You could imagine, say, Gandalf saying this as he left on some mission.

The second version is perfectly good idiomatic English.